# Extracting contents of two tables from web data

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

How can I retrieve all `td` information from this html data:

```
<h1>All staff</h1>
<h2>Manager</h2>
<table class="StaffList">
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <th>Name</th>
            <th>Post title</th>
            <th>Telephone</th>
            <th>Email</th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <a href="http://profiles.strx.usc.com/Profile.aspx?Id=Jon.Staut">Jon Staut</a>
            </td>
            <td>Line Manager</td>
            <td>0160 315 3832</td>
            <td>
                <a href="mailto:Jon.staut@strx.usc.com">Jon.staut@strx.usc.com</a> &nbsp;</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
<h2>Junior Staff</h2>
<table class="StaffList">
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <th>Name</th>
            <th>Post title</th>
            <th>Telephone</th>
            <th>Email</th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <a href="http://profiles.strx.usc.com/Profile.aspx?Id=Peter.Boone">Peter Boone</a>
            </td>
            <td>Mailer</td>
            <td>0160 315 3834</td>
            <td>
                <a href="mailto:Peter.Boone@strx.usc.com">Peter.Boone@strx.usc.com&nbsp;</a>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <a href="http://profiles.strx.usc.com/Profile.aspx?Id=John.Peters">John Peters</a>
            </td>
            <td>Builder</td>
            <td>0160 315 3837</td>
            <td>
                <a href="mailto:John.Peters@strx.usc.com">John.Peters@strx.usc.com</a>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Here's my code that generated an error:

```
response =requests.get(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(response.text, 'html.parser')
table = soup.findAll('table', attrs={'class': 'StaffList'})

list_of_rows = []
for row in table.findAll('tr'): #2 rows found in table -loop through
    list_of_cells = []
    for cell in row.findAll('td'): # each cell in in a row
        text = cell.text.replace('&nbsp','')
        list_of_cells.append(text)
    #print list_of_cells
    list_of_rows.append(list_of_cells) 
#print all cells in the two rows
print list_of_rows
```

Error message:

```
AttributeError: 'ResultSet' object has no attribute 'findAll'
```

What do I need to do to make the code output all the information in the two web tables?

Comment: Why don't you try directly `soup.findAll('td')`?

Answer (score 2):

The problem starts at this line:

```
table = soup.findAll('table', attrs={'class': 'StaffList'})
```

The `findAll` returns an array which has no attribute `findAll`.

Simply, change the `findAll` to `find`:
table = soup.find('table', attrs={'class': 'StaffList'})

Answer (score 1):

Alternatively, you can use CSS selector expression to return *`tr` elements from the `StaffList` table* without having to extract the `table` first :

```
for row in soup.select('table.StaffList tr'): #2 rows found in table -loop through
   ......
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for suggestions guys. Problem now solved after replacing 2 lines of code:

The first one:

```
table = soup.findAll('table', attrs={'class': 'StaffList'})
```

replaced with:

```
table = soup.findAll('tr')
```

The second one:

```
for row in table.findAll('tr'):
```

replaced with:

```
for row in table:
```